# Attach my projects database to Visual Studio's Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have created a connectionStirng in app.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContext2" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
    Initial Catalog=DatabaseContext2;
    Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And created this code...

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var db = new DatabaseContext2();
        db.PeopleTable1.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs0" });
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}

public class DatabaseContext2 : System.Data.Entity.DbContext  {
    public DbSet<Person> PeopleTable1 { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

public class Person {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

According to a tutorial I'm following, the database should now appear in 
Server Explorer > Data Connections. 
But it doesnt. How can I make it appear? 
E.g. how would I go about adding it under: Server Explorer > Database Connections > Add Connection ...

I have checked the registry and LocalDB is installed.

I am on Visual Studio 2012. It uses EntityFrameworks 6.

The code works when I run it - I just want to be able to visualise the tables

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out:

Server Explorer > Add Connection >

Microsoft SQL Server Database File

Database - browse for your .sdf

and click OK